# How to publish unpublished nodes programmatically

Tags: 7, database

I have some unpublished nodes, for which I have their node IDs. How can I programmatically publish them?
Is it correct to achieve it in custom module using a query like the following?

```
db_query("UPDATE {node} SET status = 1 WHERE nid = %d", $nid)
```

Comment: Although it's not the cleanest one it's one of the faster.

Comment: The fundamental problem with this method is that it does not update `node_revision`, so it will cause inconsistency.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Using `db_query()` is a Drupal 6 method, which is not used in Drupal 7. 
To achieve your job I suggest this code (without any manual query).

```
// load the node object
$node = node_load($nid);
// set status property to 1
$node->status = 1;
// re-save the node
node_save($node);
```

If you have more node ID, and you want to publish all those nodes, you can use the following code.

```
$nids = array();
// Load all nodes in one go for better performance.
$nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  // set status property to 1
  $node->status = 1;
  // re-save the node
  node_save($node);
}
```

Comment: Huh? `db_query` is a Drupal 7 method too. Just takes different arguments.

Comment: @andrewtweber, Yes now it is a part of drupal but  look at the first version of drupal 7 and then claim!!!

Comment: Which hook shall I use this?I have added inside hook_node_submit but I am taking an error.Any help?

Comment: @sokratis in hook_form_alter add a custom `submit` handler to your from then in custom submit handler yu can use something like this.

Comment: Don't forget the quotes.  
$node->status = "1";

Comment: @SelwynPolit worked with out quotes, also you can set it to TRUE;

Comment: @zhilevan In total i have 30,000 nodes. I made all the 30,000 nodes as unpublished. Now among the 30,000 I want only 900 nodes as publish. How can i achieve this? Where i will add the node ids in the above code?

Comment: If the status isn't saved, be aware there might be a `hook_node_presave()` function overriding it. Looking at you ed_classified module and your `classified_node_presave()` function....

Answer (score 8):

when you are using node_load(), node_load_multiple() for loading a(multiple) noad(s) there are many hooks would be invoked by modules, such as **hook_node_load**, **hook_node_operations**, **hook_node_prepare**, **hook_node_accesse**. But by performing query directly on drupal schema those hooks will be ignored and leads to many issues.

The Queries are:

```
db_query("UPDATE {node} SET `status` = '1' WHERE `nid` =:nid ;"
    ,array(':nid'=>$node->nid));

db_query("UPDATE {node_revision} SET `status` = '1' WHERE `nid` =:nid AND  `vid` =:vid;"
    ,array(':nid'=>$node->nid,'vid'=> $node->vid));
```

Just use above code If node_load() or node_load_multiple() not working because of running out of available memory.