# Publish content on user unblock event Drupal 7

Tags: 7, rules, users

I know that this is most probably and easy question but I simply can't get it to work. I have a custom module which generates a form to create a content (unpublished) of a certain type and also register the anonymous user creating that content with a username and password.

I am using the [User verification](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_verify) module  to send a validation mail, and when the client clicks the link the account is unblocked.

I want a rule (I tried using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module) to publish the content when the account is *unblocked* or *validated* (i need it to work on one of these to events) , but I can't find either of these events, nor can I manage to set the data selector to publish that specific content when setting the action to **publish content**.

If anyone can explain to me what I am missing or doing wrong it would help me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your custom module you could use a [hook_user_update](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_update/7) and if the $account->original->status == 0 & $account->status == 1 (meaning that the user just got active [untested]), publish the content.

something like:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implementation of hook_user_update()
 */
function MODULE_user_update(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  if($account->status && $account->status != $account->original->status) {
    // with the user id you can find (i suppose) the content this user has just 
    // created and publish it, using something like the link below
  }
}
```

[publish-unpublish](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/43801/publish-unpublished-node-programmatically)

Comment: and this function runs no matter when the user update happens? That would be pretty nice. I will try it tomorow and update with the results. Thank you

Comment: I tried to use the hook to simply change the username but it's not triggered by the User verification module ... Should I go and edit the contributed module (my experience says NO ) or am I still missing something?

Comment: No, don't do that.You could check if the contrib module exposes a hook you could implement on that particular state of the user or something?Note:you might need to user_save($account) in the hook_user_update for this to work?

Comment: Now you lost me. What do you mean by "exposes a hook you could implement on that particular state of the user"? I am still new to drupal , 1 month and counting

Comment: from what I understood in the code , the module has a _user_verify($account,$code) function which is called when the user clicks the validation link . If the code provided by the user coresponds with the one assisgned to his account , then the function _user_verify_cleanup is called ( this function is called in many other scenarios), a variable $success is set to TRUE and the user is unblocked (db_update('users')->fields(array('status' => 1))->execute(). How can I set my hook to interact with that event without tampering the contrib module code?

Comment: I finally understood what you meant and yes, the module does provide a hook for that state of the user called hook_user_verify_verified. It works perfectly now. Thank you very much for the help

Comment: Excellent, glad it helped, a good chance to understand the hooks system - and if u do that, you understand how Drupal works, cheers